# JPA remove detached entity

Tags: jpa, orm

I've just begun working with JPA and hibernate, and I have been able to insert  query and update on one table, but I cannot seem to delete an entity.  Even after I attach the entity with the merge function, the program insists it is detached.  Here is the relevant code:

```
public User getUserByEmail(String email) throws DAOException{
    User user = null; 
    EntityManager em = null; //declare here for use in finally block
    try{                        
        //get em for use
        EntityManagerFactory factory = JPAUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        //setup return type as user
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> userRoot = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
        //populate the where clause
        criteriaQuery.where(cb.equal(userRoot.get("email"), cb.parameter(String.class, "email")));          
        Query query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        query.setParameter("email", email);
        //actually run the query on db
        user = (User) query.getSingleResult();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        DAOException dE = new DAOException(2, "getUserByEmail failed", ex);
        //TODO log
        throw dE;
    }       
    //cleanup
    finally{
        if(em != null && em.isOpen()){
            em.close();
        }
    }
    return user; //if not found, will still be null
}



@Override
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see dao.IUserDAO#deleteUser(java.lang.String)
 */
public void deleteUser(String email) throws DAOException {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    EntityManager em = null;
    EntityTransaction trans = null;
    try{            
        //search user on email
        User user = getUserByEmail(email);          
        //check we found user with specified email
        if(user != null){
            //setup for interaction with database
            entityManagerFactory = JPAUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();
            em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            //alterations of db must occur in scope of transaction
            trans = em.getTransaction();
            trans.begin();
            em.merge(user); //TODO update find to take transaction as parameter
            em.remove(user);
            trans.commit();
            //explicitly flush here
            em.flush();             
        }else{
            //TODO we didn't find the user
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        DAOException dE = new DAOException(6, "delete failed", ex);
        //TODO log
        trans.rollback();
        throw dE;
    }finally{
        if(em != null && em.isOpen()){
            em.close();
        }
    }       
}
```

And here is the output from the eclipse console:
"Removing a deattached instance of User#1".

Could someone explain why this bean is still deattached after I explicitly called merge? Also, how would I fix this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The content of the specified detached entity object is copied into an
>   existing managed entity object with the same identity (i.e. same type
>   and primary key). If the EntityManager does not manage such an entity
>   object yet a new managed entity object is constructed. The detached
>   object itself, however, remains unchanged and detached.

Even after merge the detached object itself remains detached, merge will return the new created merged entity

```
user = em.merge(user); //TODO update find to take transaction as parameter
em.remove(user);
```